# Remove Join Relations in Elastic Search 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to remove relations in Elastic Search 7.x?
It says in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html#_parent_join_restrictions) that "It is possible to add a new relation to an existing join field." but it doesn't say anything about removing relations.

For example, when I put a mapping onto an index, it initially works.

```
PUT /randomindex/_mapping
{
    "properties":{
        "my_property": {
             "type":"join",
               "relations": {
                    "parent_1": "child_1"
                  }
                }
              }
}
```

Then, when I try to change it, I get an error:

```
PUT /randomindex/_mapping
{
    "properties":{
                "my_property": {
                  "type":"join",
                  "relations": {
                    "parent_2": "child_2"
                  }
                }
              }
}
```

This is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[tiebreaker-0000000002][xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx][indices:admin/mapping/put]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "invalid update for join field [my_property]:\n[cannot remove parent [parent_1] in join field [my_property]]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```